# Problem compiling project with CorePlot

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-plot

Today I tried to compile a project with CorePlot.

All the time I get the following errors:

```
  ".objc_class_name_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNotificationCenter in libCorePlot.a(CPGraph.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNotificationCenter in libCorePlot.a(CPXYPlotSpace.o)
 ".objc_class_name_NSException", referenced from:
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPScatterPlot.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPBarPlot.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPGraph.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPGradient.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPLayer.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPXYPlotSpace.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPTheme.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPTradingRangePlot.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPAxisLabel.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPAxisTitle.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libCorePlot.a(CPXYAxis.o)
 ".objc_class_name_UIView", referenced from:
 .objc_class_name_CPLayerHostingView in libCorePlot.a(CPLayerHostingView.o)
 ".objc_class_name_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libCorePlot.a(CPPlot.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libCorePlot.a(CPScatterPlot.o)
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libCorePlot.a(CPBarPlot.o)      [ . . . ]
```

I hope someone can help me.

EDIT: It's working if I try to compile for device but not for simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I missed including the headerfiles of framework by setting header search path in projectsettings. => double-click Target => bild => search for **Header Search Path** set values to: **recursiv = YES** search and **../framework/**

It should look like this:
[image]
[image]

Download framework here: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=alpharelease_0.1.zip&can=2&q=

Copy framework folder next to project's folder.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the problem i was having earlier, but to my best guess it was only fixed by adding the rest of the code, it might still be there hidden behind these 7 other errors.  I have attached the complete view controller.m file for more experienced eyes.

```
//
```

//  SOTC_CorePlotViewController.m
//  SOTC-CorePlot
//
//  Created by NFCU 98972 on 8/18/10.
//  Copyright 2010 **MyCompanyName**. All rights reserved.
//

## import "SOTC_CorePlotViewController.h"

@implementation SOTC_CorePlotViewController

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecords {
    return 51;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum

               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    double val = (index/5.0)-5;
    if(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX)
    { return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:val]; }
    else
    { 
        if(plot.identifier == @"X Squared Plot")
        { return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:val*val]; }
        else
        { return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1/val]; }
    }
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];

CPLayerHostingView *hostingView = (CPLayerHostingView *)self.view;
hostingView.hostedLayer = graph;
graph.paddingLeft = 20.0;
graph.paddingTop = 20.0;
graph.paddingRight = 20.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 20.0;

CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-6) 
                                               length:CPDecimalFromFloat(12)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-5) 
                                               length:CPDecimalFromFloat(30)];

CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5"];
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLabelOffset = 3.0f;

axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5"];
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLabelOffset = 3.0f;

CPScatterPlot *xSquaredPlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] 
                                initWithFrame:graph.defaultPlotSpace.bounds] autorelease];
xSquaredPlot.identifier = @"X Squared Plot";
xSquaredPlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
xSquaredPlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor redColor];
xSquaredPlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:xSquaredPlot];

CPPlotSymbol *greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:[CPColor greenColor]];
greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
xSquaredPlot.defaultPlotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;  

CPScatterPlot *xInversePlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] 
                                initWithFrame:graph.defaultPlotSpace.bounds] autorelease];
xInversePlot.identifier = @"X Inverse Plot";
xInversePlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
xInversePlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blueColor];
xInversePlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:xInversePlot];
```

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

  // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
  }
- (void)viewDidUnload {
  [super viewDidUnload];
  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
  // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
  }
- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
  }

@end